# Use manually assigned ipv6 address

Tags: windows, ipv6, windows-8.1

I have a /48, and from this I assigned a /64 to this lan

I have a windows 8.1, which I want to use an assigned ip for outgoing adress.

But I keep getting an automatically assigned address.

```
netsh interface ipv6>show addresses


Interface 2: Ethernet

Addr Type  DAD State   Valid Life Pref. Life Address
---------  ----------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------
Manual     Preferred     infinite   infinite 2001:DB8:1234:8000::1111:2222
Public     Preferred  29d23h53m20s 6d23h53m20s 2001:DB8:1234:8000:21d:9ff:fe24:656c
Other      Preferred     infinite   infinite fe80::21d:9ff:fe24:656c%2
```

(2001:DB8:1234:: is the docummentation example network)

I only want the 1111:2222 adress ised as outgoing, not the one generated from the mac.
(I want to use this as a first level access-control)

I have disabled privacy extensions:

```
netsh interface ipv6>show global
Querying active state...

General Global Parameters
---------------------------------------------
Default Hop Limit                   : 128 hops
Neighbor Cache Limit                : 256 entries per interface
Route Cache Limit                   : 128 entries per compartment
Reassembly Limit                    : 33537408 bytes
ICMP Redirects                      : enabled
Source Routing Behavior             : dontforward
Task Offload                        : enabled
Dhcp Media Sense                    : enabled
Media Sense Logging                 : disabled
MLD Level                           : all
MLD Version                         : version3
Multicast Forwarding                : disabled
Group Forwarded Fragments           : disabled
Randomize Identifiers               : disabled
Address Mask Reply                  : disabled
Minimum MTU                         : 1280

Current Global Statistics
---------------------------------------------
Number of Compartments              : 1
Number of NL clients                : 5
Number of FL providers              : 5

netsh interface ipv6>show interface ethernet

Interface Ethernet Parameters
----------------------------------------------
IfLuid                             : ethernet_7
IfIndex                            : 2
State                              : connected
Metric                             : 10
Link MTU                           : 1500 bytes
Reachable Time                     : 22500 ms
Base Reachable Time                : 30000 ms
Retransmission Interval            : 1000 ms
DAD Transmits                      : 1
Site Prefix Length                 : 64
Site Id                            : 1
Forwarding                         : disabled
Advertising                        : disabled
Neighbor Discovery                 : enabled
Neighbor Unreachability Detection  : enabled
Router Discovery                   : enabled
Managed Address Configuration      : disabled
Other Stateful Configuration       : disabled
Weak Host Sends                    : disabled
Weak Host Receives                 : disabled
Use Automatic Metric               : enabled
Ignore Default Routes              : disabled
Advertised Router Lifetime         : 1800 seconds
Advertise Default Route            : disabled
Current Hop Limit                  : 64
Force ARPND Wake up patterns       : disabled
Directed MAC Wake up patterns      : disabled
ECN capability                     : application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These instructions on http://blog.yogi-way.lv/2013/01/ipv6-and-slaac.html are probably what you need:

> To disable SLAAC in Windows first check what NIC you would like to
>   disable auto configuration on with:
>
> ```
> netsh interface ipv6 show interface
> ```
>
> Then execute
>
> ```
> netsh interface ipv6 set interface X routerdiscovery=disabled
> ```
>
> where X is desired interface index from the show command output.
>
> To disable privacy execute (command works globally for all
>   interfaces):
>
> ```
> netsh interface ipv6 set privacy state=disable store=persistent
> netsh interface ipv6 set global randomizeidentifiers=disabled store=persistent
> ```

One warning though: if you disable listening to router advertisements you'll have to configure the IPv6 default gateway (and maybe some other settings like MTU size) manually.

Comment: Thanks, worked.
Especially when I fixed my typo of not having my default gateway on the same /64 as the machine :-)